# Can you always use "NOT EXISTS" instead of "Not in"?

Tags: mysql, not-exists

I have the Following Schema :
Book(ISBN,Title,Genre)
Published(ISBN,Publishernumber)

The Query : **What are the publisher numbers of the publishers that exclusively publish books of the genre “Computer Science”?**

I tried building the query using "Not in" and it worked fine.

```
SELECT p.Publishernumber 

FROM published p , book b 

WHERE b.ISBN=p.ISBN AND b.Genre = "CS" AND p.publishernumber not in  (

SELECT p.publishernumber 

 FROM Book b , published p 

 WHERE b.ISBN=p.ISBN AND b.Genre != "CS" );
```

How can i build the same query using "Not Exists" ?

Answer (score 2):

To use `NOT EXISTS` you need to use a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT p.Publishernumber 
FROM published p 
JOIN book b ON b.ISBN=p.ISBN
WHERE b.Genre = "CS" AND NOT EXISTS  (
    SELECT 1  
    FROM Book b
    JOIN published p2 ON b.ISBN=p.ISBN
    WHERE b.Genre != "CS" AND p2.publishernumber = p.publishernumber);
```